# import function from other scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following scripts:

```
 src/
     __init__.py
     evaluation.py
     main.py
```

the scripts for evaluation.py is following,

```
from collections import Counter
def f_score(pred, answers):

     '''

     f1 = (2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
     return f1
```

evaluation.py contains a function called 'f_score', I want to use f_score function in my main.py

In the main.py, I do following,

```
 from evaluation import *
 f_score()
```

I received the error message: NameError: name 'f_score' is not defined.

However, if I do

```
 from evaluation import f_score
 f_score()
```

This works. 
May I ask why?

Comment: can you post the evaluation.py code?

Comment: Is there an `__all__ = [ ... ]` section near the top of evaluation.py?  If there is and it doesn't contain `f_score`, that'll be your problem

Comment: @JackHoman I updated evaluation.py

Comment: @KindStranger I don't have __all__ = [ ... ]. How should I add it?

Comment: What you're saying doesn't really make sense then. As @KindStranger was getting at, unless `__all__` is defined in a module, `from evaluation import * ` imports everything from the module.

Comment: You should call f_score() with evaluation.f_score() in your first case.

Comment: @JackHoman thanks. I add`__all__`, then it works now!!

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, how did you define `__all__`? Adding all shouldn't have fixed the problem unless you define `__all__` as `__all__ = ['f_score']`. What you're describing sounds more like a spelling error than a procedural thing.

Comment: BTW, not answering your question, but why don't you simply `from evaluation import f_score`? That is the better way to import anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the latest python update. When I try it, it works seamlessly.

```
from file1 import *
input = input("Enter:")
if input == "hi":
    hi_back()
```

This prints out "hi" as that is the function in file1.

Make sure the modules are in the same path, as you have done.
Here's how I import things from modules I created:

```
import file1 as f1
f1.function1()
```

This is my preferred way of handling it and makes life easier when you get to importing many different modules in one file. I see in your code that you have just three ''' in the function but none to end the comment. This could be a problem as the function will think there is nothing in there.
Also maybe you had a spelling error? Happens to the best of us :)